# Why is the "using" directive still needed in C++11 to bring forward methods from the base class that are overloaded in the derived class

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, overloading, using-directives

The example below gets the following compiled error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:26:8: error: no match for call to ‘(Derived) (p1&)’
test.cpp:14:8: note: candidate is:
test.cpp:16:10: note: void Derived::operator()(const p2&)
test.cpp:16:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘p1’ to ‘const p2&’
```

It was my understanding this was getting changed in C++11 so you weren't required to put the using statement in. Is that not correct? Is there some other way around this?

Example (Compiled with gcc 4.7 using --std=c++11):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct p1{};
struct p2{};

struct Base
{
    void operator()(const p1&) { cout << "p1" << endl; }
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    void operator()(const p2&) { cout << "p2" << endl; }
    //Works if I include: using Base::operator();
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    p1 p;
    p2 pp;
    Derived d;

    d(p);
    d(pp);
}
```

Comment: What would you do if you wanted to hide the base class functions? Removing the need to use the `using` declaration would be a breaking change. At least in one of the newer draft documents I see nothing changed with regard to the using declaration.

Comment: Where did you get the information about `using` no longer being necessary in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, no, this has not changed in C++11.

And the reason it has not changed is that this behavior is not an accident. The language works like this by design. There are advantages and disadvantages to it, but it's not something that just happened because the people on the standards committee forgot about it.

And no, there's no way around it. It's just how member lookup works in C++

Comment: Oh well. I was hoping maybe I could use some kind of modifier to tell the compiler to bring them foward, but I guess not :(. Thanks!

Comment: There is. That's what the `using` statement does. ;)

Answer (score 3):

> It was my understanding this was getting changed in C++11 so you weren't required to put the using statement in. Is that not correct?

No, member functions can still be hidden in C++11.

> Is there some other way around this?

Using declarations are the intended remedy.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify the situation: I can't imagine this *ever* changing in C++. To even hope to make it a tenable change, you'd have to tighten up type safety to the point that it would no longer be compatible with C (e.g., you'd pretty much have to eliminate all implicit conversions).

The situation is fairly simple: right now, name lookup stops at the first scope found that includes at least one instance of the name being used. If that instance of the name doesn't match the way you tried to use the name, then compilation fails.

Consider the obvious alternative: instead of stopping searching at that point, the compiler continues searching out scopes, created essentially an overload set of all those names, and then picked the one that matched the best.

In a case like this, a seemingly trivial change at an outer scope could (completely) change the meaning of some code, quite unintentionally. Consider something like this, for example:

```
int i;

int main() { 
    long i;

    i = 1;

    std::cout << i;
    return 0;
}
```

Under the current rules, the meaning of this is clear and unequivocal: the `i=1;` assigns the value 1 to the `i` defined local to `main`.

Under the revised rules, that would be open to question -- in fact, it probably shouldn't be the case. The compiler would find both instances of `i`, and since `1` has type `int`, it should probably be matched up with the global `i` instead. When we print out `i`, the compiler finds an overload that takes a `long`, so it prints out the local `i` (which still contains garbage).

Note that this adds another wrinkle though: the `cout << i;` would be referring to the local `i` *because* there was an overload that could work with it. So instead of the type of the variable controlling the overload that was used, you'd have the available overloads also controlling the variable that was used. I'm not sure, but I'd guess this makes parsing *much* more difficult (quite possibly an NP-hard or NP-complete problem).

In short, any code that (intentionally or otherwise) used almost any kind of implicit conversion at an inner scope, this seemingly unrelated changes at outer scopes could suddenly change the meaning of that code completely -- and as in the example above, easily break it quite thoroughly in the process.

In the case above, with only a half dozen lines of code, it's pretty easy to figure out what's going on. Consider, however, what happens when (for example) you define a class in a header, then include that header into some other file -- the compiler looks at the other code where you included the header, find a better match, and suddenly code you swore was thoroughly vetted and tested breaks most spectacularly.

With headers, it would (or at least could) get even worse though. You define your class, and include the header into two different files. One of those files defines a variable, function, etc. at outer scope and the other doesn't. Now code in one file using name X refers to the global, while code in the other file refers to the local, because the global doesn't happen to be visible in that file. This would completely break modularity, and render virtually all code completely broken (or at least breakable).

Of course, there would be other possibilities that might not be quite this broken. One possibility would be to eliminate *all* implicit conversions, so only a perfect type match would ever be considered. This would eliminate most of the obvious problems, but only at the expense of *completely* breaking compatibility with C (not to mention probably making a lot of programmers quite unhappy). Another possibility would be to search like it does now, stopping at the first scope where it found a match -- then continuing to outer scopes if and only if compilation was going to fail if it used that name at the inner scope.

Either of these could work, but (at the very least) you'd need quite a few restrictions to keep them from leading to almost insane levels of confusion. Just for example, consider something like `a =1; a = '\2';` Right now, those *must* refer to the same variable -- but with the first of these rules, they wouldn't.

With some special cases, you could probably eliminate that particular oddity too -- for example, use the current rules for looking up variable names, and new/separate rules only for function names.

Summary: the simple/obvious way to do this would create a language that was almost irretrievably broken. Modifications to prevent that would be possible, but only at the expense of throwing away compatibility with both C and essentially all existing C++ code. The latter might be possible in a brand new language, but for a language that's already well established like C++ (especially on that became established largely based on backward compatibility -- C++ again).

Comment: While I don't think that overload resolution (which is where the using declaration takes effect) can apply to variables, and while I believe that the question is only dealing with inheritance relationships, the exact same reasoning applies changing `main` and the global namespace by a derived and base classes and the `i` for a function for which two different overloads taking `int` and `long` exist in the different contexts. +1